# C++ MFC list control with horizontal scroll bar

Tags: c++, mfc, scrollbar, clistctrl

I got here to ask this question because none of the solutions I've found satisfied me or even worked. My problem is pretty straightforward.

I have a `CListCtrl` in C++ with a lot of columns. They don't fit to the width of the list, so I have to add a horizontal scroll bar.

I tried with `EnableScrollbar`, `ShowScrollBar`, `SetScrollPos`, but none of them worked. How do I create a horizontal scrollbar and show it properly?

Comment: I've done this, but it was painful. I don't remember all the hoops I had to jump through to make it work, but it seems like I had to keep track of the widest string and set the scroll width accordingly. I also seem to recall something about scrolling to the top, then back to the current position when the width changed to get the bar to update properly. Too long ago to remember many details though.

Comment: The scroll bar should appear automatically  - "The items of a list control can display only within the control, if there are too many of them or the total width of the items is larger than the control can display, it would be equipped with either a vertical scroll bar, a horizontal scroll bar, or both. If you want to prevent scroll bars from displaying even if the list’s items go beyond the allocated rectangle, set the No Scroll property to True or create the control with the LVS_NOSCROLL style." This source can help - http://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/listcontrol.htm

Comment: Indeed it should appear. However, it does not. Is there some kind of property that suppresses its apparition, disables or hiding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the LVS_REPORT style it should just add the scrollbar for you (as long as the columns exceed the width of the ListCtrl). No special trickery needed.

Is it possible that your CListCtrl is sized bigger than it's container window and therefore not adding a scrollbar? If it's still not working please add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: I solved the problmem. Both SChepurin and snowdude were right. My problem was when I wrote the OnSize method. I used MoveWindow, with the width parameter larger than it should have been, so there was no event that called the appearance of the scroll bar.